# Unable to Insert Data into MySql Table using username from another $_POST function

Tags: php, mysql, post, forms, http-post

```
    echo "Hello : ".$_SESSION['doc_username'];


    //username sent from a different page by post method

    $username = $_POST['username'];

    echo "<p><strong>Showing Health Information for : </strong>";echo $username; "</p>";


    if($_POST['submit']) 
    {

    $height = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['height']);
    $weight = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['weight']);


if($height && $weight)
{
    require "dbc.php";
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE patient_info SET 
    height='$height',weight='$weight' WHERE username='$username'");
    echo "Patient Data Saved!";
}
 else 
{
    echo "All fields are required!";
}
```

The problem with this code is not in the mysql query. I have already checked it for syntax errors using phpcodechecker and there was none. There were more variables to be inserted into the database but height and weight will do for example. My problem is I am getting the username from a different page by POST method and I cannot save it in a way that it could be used by the "submit" value in this form to enable updating of that particular username. Because the username from the other form which $username cannot be referred to within the $_POST in this page, thus the username variable is blank when I click the submit button. How can I get a username sent from another page to this page by POST to be used in this form in the UPDATE query. The form does send the username to this page successfully which is proven when I can echo the username out. But it cannot be used by the form in this page. Please help as I am very new to PHP codes and I'm trying the best that I can.

Comment: Where is your `<form>` code?

Comment: may be i think username is in session ?

Comment: Paragraph formatting please

Comment: @YogeshSuthar the <form> code is in a different page for the username and this page's form is in the HTML section which the <form action="refers back to this page" method="POST">.

Comment: @ArunKillu The username is not in the session coz another user (user_doctor) is going to edit the patient's data by referring to the patient's username. That is why I need the username.

Comment: ok then pass with url or as a hidden form variable

Comment: @yogeshsuthar      The thing is I am using a drop-down box to choose the username and I cannot refer to the session because it is a different logged on user trying to edit another user's data,thus the drop-down box. Because of this I have to send this $username into the if($_POST['submit']) section of this page, but because when I press submit the saved $username is lost thus the query cannot be executed as it lacks the "WHERE" clause which is referring to the $username. This is my problem.

Comment: @Tyson It will be better if you show your form code.Otherwise you will get any unnecessary random answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all replace the line:

From:

```
if($_POST['submit'])
```

to:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

If you are using a combobox then check that you have provided the **name** parameter in its markup like:

```
<select name="submit">
...
</select>
```

[EDIT]

> After analyzing the code it is found that the HTML markup 
>   was written after form element. I think this is the issue. Rest
>   appears to be Ok.

Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: The thing is I am using a drop-down box to choose the username and I cannot refer to the session because it is a different logged on user trying to edit another user's data,thus the drop-down box. Because of this I have to send this $username into the if($_POST['submit'])
section of this page, but because when I press submit the saved $username is lost thus the query cannot be executed as it lacks the "WHERE" clause which is referring to the $username. This is my problem.

Comment: so your drop down must be like this: <select name="submit">...</select>

Comment: The thing is I cannot edit my $_SESSION because that $_SESSION is tracking the current logged in user so that is why I am using the method of obtaining username from client-side and using that to run the query but I can obtain it from client-side the problem is when I try to pass that $username variable into the $_POST['submit'] in this form and when I hit submit the value in $username is lost. That is the problem. To retain the saved $username even after the submit button is clicked

Comment: if you can give your e-mail I can send u the two concerning pages so you can see for yourself how the passing happens from one page to the other for this problem... Please I really need help because of this my Final Year Project is stagnant. Please consider my problem.

Comment: Email:  info(at)asimishaq(dot)com

Comment: I have sent you a message via Gmail. My email is tysonjasmin(at)gmail(dot)com

Comment: No Asim it did not work. I think the problem lies in the patient_info.php page. Still trying to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

On the initial page, add a hidden form element named "username" with the value you want to carry over into the form submission.

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="the.user.name">
```

Comment: The thing is I am using a drop-down box to choose the username and I cannot refer to the session because it is a different logged on user trying to edit another user's data,thus the drop-down box. Because of this I have to send this $username into the if($_POST['submit']) section of this page, but because when I press submit the saved $username is lost thus the query cannot be executed as it lacks the "WHERE" clause which is referring to the $username. This is my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may store user name in session on request when it passed, or add to getparam of request or in hidden element of form:

```
<form action="procces.php?username={real_user_name}">
```

OR

```
<form>
   <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="{real_user_name}"/> 
   ...
</form>
```

Comment: The thing is I am using a drop-down box to choose the username and I cannot refer to the session because it is a different logged on user trying to edit another user's data,thus the drop-down box. Because of this I have to send this $username into the if($_POST['submit']) section of this page, but because when I press submit the saved $username is lost thus the query cannot be executed as it lacks the "WHERE" clause which is referring to the $username. This is my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>" />
```

The username in first page was transferred to another paged where you can edit it
As second page also contains a form so we also need to add username field int as when it will be posted the username will also be sent.

This had to be inserted into the 2nd form to retain the data sent from the previous in the previous page so that it can be used for the query in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You may the user name in the session (supposed you have one, if not, you seriously should anyway):

Populating a form field like @tslocum suggested also needs to get the user name from somewhere. This is a quite common solution, but where does the user name come from?

There might be some time between submitting the name and rendering the current page, so as this is stateless but you need a state (State "we have a given username already") within that page during rendering and processing, take a look at $_SESSION global variable.

my approach:

Post 1:

```
....
$_SESSION['currentUser'] = $_POST['username'];
// you need some checks over here, don't use 
// that as typed here, left out just for clearness.
```

... some time

Post 2:
...

```
$username = $_SESSION['currentUser'];
// again some checks over here!
```

read about $_SESSION in the php manuals.

Comment: The thing is I cannot edit my $_SESSION because that $_SESSION is tracking the current logged in user so that is why I am using the method of obtaining username from client-side and using that to run the query but I can obtain it from client-side the problem is when I try to pass that $username variable into the $_POST['submit'] in this form and when I hit submit the value in $username is lost. That is the problem. To retain the saved $username even after the submit button is clicked.